# are SHA-1 certificates are different for debug and release modes?

Tags: android, google-maps, sha1

i ve created release key store and i got another google map api . Google map is working on debug mode but on release mode its not. do i need another SHA-1 certificate ? 
thanks for your helps .

Comment: Both keystore are different that means you should generate SHA-1 from both

Answer (score 1):

Yes SHA1 certificate for debug and release mode are different.You can find different SHA1 for reease mode(When genearting apk) and debug mode(Window->preferences)

For eg:if map is used then you shoud create 2 map api keys in google console

Answer (score 0):

When compiling with debug and release key store the application is signed with different credentials. These credentials are used by Google to identify who has access to different APIs.

You probably need to log into the Google Developer Console and add details about the new key store.

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you build your app in Release mode, Android Studio (I hope that's the IDE you're using) will prompt you to create a new KeyStore (if you don't already have one) and then you needta use this KeyStore  and update your SHA-1 keys on Google Developer Console, otherwise, all your google APIs will not work.

Answer (score 0):

run this code pro:

- cd android
- ./gradlew signingreport

[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzKnT.png)

for debug mode:
add SHA1 and SHA-256

for release mode:
add SHA1 and SHA-256